# how to connect mysql server to xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

can anyone help? I'm new in web developing.. and I want to know that does XAMPP need a MYSQL server to start xampp services? I only install xampp but my files on htdocs wont work.

Comment: start xampp turn on apache and mysql services go to your browser type localhost

Answer (score 0):

No it wont required Mysql to start. 
 You can use xampp only to serve static web pages Also.
you can monitor the setting from xampp control panel Also.